# Spark dataframe explode function

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Can anyone please explain why case `Row`, `Seq[Row]` are used after the explode of a `dataframe` field which has collection of elements.
And also can you please explain me the reason why asInstanceOf is required to get the values from the exploded field?

Here is the syntax:

```
val explodedDepartmentWithEmployeesDF = departmentWithEmployeesDF.explode(departmentWithEmployeesDF("employees")) {     
                          case Row(employee: Seq[Row]) => 
                          employee.map(employee =>
                          Employee(employee(0).asInstanceOf[String], 
                          employee(1).asInstanceOf[String], employee(2).asInstanceOf[String]) ) }
```

Answer (score 2):

First I will note, that I can not explain why your `explode()` turns into `Row(employee: Seq[Row])` as I don't know the schema of your DataFrame. I have to assume it has to do with the structure of your data.

Not knowing you original data, I have created a small data set to work from

```
scala> val df = sc.parallelize( Array( (1, "dsfds dsf dasf dsf dsf d"), (2, "2344 2353 24 23432 234"))).toDF("id", "text")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: int, text: string]
```

If I now map over it, you can se that it returns rows containing data of type Any.

```
scala> df.map {case row: Row => (row(0), row(1)) }
res21: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Any, Any)] = MapPartitionsRDD[17] at map at <console>:33
```

You have basically lost type information, which is why you need to explicitly specify the type when you want to use the data in the row

```
scala> df.map {case row: Row => (row(0).asInstanceOf[Int], row(1).asInstanceOf[String]) }
res22: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Int, String)] = MapPartitionsRDD[18] at map at <console>:33
```

So, in order to explode it, I have to do the following

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
df.explode(col("id"), col("text")) {case row: Row =>
    val id = row(0).asInstanceOf[Int]
    val words = row(1).asInstanceOf[String].split(" ")
    words.map(word => (id, word))
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
res30: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: int, text: string, _1: int, _2: string]

scala> res30 show
+---+--------------------+---+-----+
| id|                text| _1|   _2|
+---+--------------------+---+-----+
|  1|dsfds dsf dasf ds...|  1|dsfds|
|  1|dsfds dsf dasf ds...|  1|  dsf|
|  1|dsfds dsf dasf ds...|  1| dasf|
|  1|dsfds dsf dasf ds...|  1|  dsf|
|  1|dsfds dsf dasf ds...|  1|  dsf|
|  1|dsfds dsf dasf ds...|  1|    d|
|  2|2344 2353 24 2343...|  2| 2344|
|  2|2344 2353 24 2343...|  2| 2353|
|  2|2344 2353 24 2343...|  2|   24|
|  2|2344 2353 24 2343...|  2|23432|
|  2|2344 2353 24 2343...|  2|  234|
+---+--------------------+---+-----+
```

If you want named columns, you can define a case class to hold you exploded data

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
case class ExplodedData(word: String)
df.explode(col("id"), col("text")) {case row: Row =>
    val words = row(1).asInstanceOf[String].split(" ")
    words.map(word => ExplodedData(word))
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
defined class ExplodedData
res35: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: int, text: string, word: string]

scala> res35.select("id","word").show
+---+-----+
| id| word|
+---+-----+
|  1|dsfds|
|  1|  dsf|
|  1| dasf|
|  1|  dsf|
|  1|  dsf|
|  1|    d|
|  2| 2344|
|  2| 2353|
|  2|   24|
|  2|23432|
|  2|  234|
+---+-----+
```

Hope this brings some clearity.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can read more about the document and do a test first.

explode of a dataframe still return a dataframe.And it accept a lambda function f: (Row) ⇒ TraversableOnce[A] as parameter.

in the lambda function, you will match the input by case. You've already known that your input will be Row of employee, which is still a Seq of Row.So the case of input will Row(employee: Seq[Row]) , if you don't understand this part, you can learn more thing about unapply funciton in scala.

And than, employee(I believe you should use employees here), as a Seq of Row, will apply the map function to map each row to a Employee. And you will use the scala apply function to get the i'th value in this row. But the return value is an Object , so you have to use asInstanceOf to convert it into the type you expected.